# How to seed a random number generator in a safe and portable way?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, random-seed

**Background:**

Since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), it is recommended to use a `std::random_device` instead of the time to seed a random number generator. If we take a look at the [related documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device), we can read that:

> `std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine **if a non-deterministic source** (e.g. a hardware device) **is not available to the implementation**. In this case each `std::random_device` object **may generate the same number sequence**.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Let's now consider the following example:

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution distr(0, 9);

    // Print a sequence of 10 uniformly distributed random integers
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << distr(gen) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

If the system/platform does not provide a non-deterministic source, this program may/will always generate the same sequence of numbers for each run (it is actually the case on my platform).

In this case, `std::random_device` is far worse than seeding the random number generator with the current time:

```
std::mt199937 gen(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()); // time seed
```

---

**Issue:**

My concern is that if someone wants to write a program that will rely on some random generated numbers and is required:

1. To be portable
2. To guarantee non-deterministic randomness

Then `std::random_device` will not be a right fit.
On the other hand, using always a time seed would be a quite frustrating "solution" since if the given platform has a non-deterministic source available, `std::random_device` would then be "safer".

**Question:**

My question is divided in two parts:

1. Userland

   - Is there a portable way to check if such a non-deterministic source is available on the current platform?
2. Compiler-side

   - Are compilers allowed to replace `std::random_device` seeds by time seeds if the host platform has no non-deterministic source available ? Or is there something in the standard that would prevent such a replacement?
   - If the standard does not prohibit this behaviour, what would be a reason for compilers to not implement it?

---

*<sub>Perhaps these should be 2 or 3 separate questions. Since the background and issue are common, I've asked them in the same post for completeness purposes on the topic. Please let me know if I have to split them into separate questions anyway.</sub>*

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what platform are you using?

Comment: https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html Another thing to consider. I would argue that nearly all modern hardware will have a source of entropy.

Comment: @super Windows 10 with MinGW :p Perhaps this is because I compiled in debug mode.

Comment: @Fareanor I use the same configuration on this computer, g++ 9.2.0, and I get different sequences on each run using your code.

Comment: @super I'm using it through Qt-creator. Whatever, on my platform, the entropy is `0` which explains why I always get the same sequence on each run.

Comment: @Fareanor Not really. The entropy would be 0 for a PRNG, and that would not produce the same sequence each run. It's an old compiler with an incomplete (bad) implementation of `std::random_device` that's probably causing the issues for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a portable way to check if such a non-deterministic source is available on the current platform?

You can use the [`entropy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy) member function of `std::random_device` to check if the source is non-deterministic or not.  Unfortunately it is not a `static constexpr` function so you'll have to use a regular if statement like

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::size_t seed;
    if (rd.entropy())
        seed = rd();
    else
        seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution distr(0, 9);

    // Print a sequence of 10 uniformly distributed random integers
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << distr(gen) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

> Are compilers allowed to replace `std::random_device` seeds by time seeds if the host platform has no non-deterministic source available ? Or is there something in the standard that would prevent such a replacement?

That would change the observable behavior of the program so no, the compiler can't do that.

Comment: I guess the notes on the cppreference page regarding `std::random_device::entropy` implementations are important.

Comment: Oww I missed this member function in the documentation... I feel so scatterbrained. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Note: *"This function is not fully implemented in some standard libraries. For example, LLVM libc++ always returns zero even though the device is non-deterministic. In comparison, Microsoft Visual C++ implementation always returns 32, and boost.random returns 10."*